# UIView Xib header стоит на месте при скроллинге?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Я сделал детальную сцену представления где у меня вверх `Header` и внизу два вида ячеек cell. Текст достаточно длинный и при скроллинге он заходит под низ `Header` вот думаю наверное надо было сделать еще один виде ячейки, и заменить `Header`. Прикладываю свой код и скриншота.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailSoccerTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var detailSoccer: Soccer!
    var selectedSoccer = [Soccer]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    title = detailSoccer.detailTitleS

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 288
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"SoccerHeaderView",bundle:nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "SoccerHeaderView")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"SoccerTableViewCell",bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "soccerCell")


    tableView.reloadData()
    loadMatchSoccer()
       //Header
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let soccerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soccerCell", for: indexPath) as! SoccerTableViewCell

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Аналитика и обзор матча:"
        soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.textSoccer
    case 1:
        soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Прогноз на матч:"
        soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.detailPrognozS
    default:
        break
    }

 return soccerCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "SoccerHeaderView") as! SoccerHeaderView

    header.soccerName.text = detailSoccer.detailTitleS

    return header
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 300
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func loadMatchSoccer() {

    let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>
    query.whereKey("detailTitleS", equalTo: detailSoccer.detailTitleS)
    query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.selectedSoccer = objects!
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        } else {
            print(error!)
        }
}
}
```

}